# Compiling boost flags with explicit location on boost binaries

Tags: c++, boost

I am compiling a project that needs `boost::filesystem`. I have included the following flags in my compilation step:

```
g++ -Wall -ggdb -Werror -std=c++11 -lboost_system 
    -lboost_filesystem -I /custom/path/to/boost_1_67_0 
    -o build/main build/cp.o build/walk.o build/diff.o build/main.o
```

and I get an error:

```
build/cp.o: In function `boost::filesystem::relative(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&)':
/custom/path/boost_1_67_0/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:690: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::relative(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
build/cp.o: In function `boost::filesystem::weakly_canonical(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
/custom/path/boost_1_67_0/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:728: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::weakly_canonical(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I suspect that this is due to the fact that I have various other `boost::filesystem` binaries, some of which don't have `relative` and `weakly_canonical` in their versions. I don't really know where to supply the argument to specify the location of the binaries either. I suspect it's something to do with the flags `lboost_system` and `lboost_filesystem` where I can supply the location.

**I am currently in process of building the .so's but I can see that the filesystem .so is already successfully built at `/custom/path/boost_1_67_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/threading-multi/libboost_filesystem.so.1.67.0`,** so I want to point to that in the mean time. Building the library is taking a really long time.

So is it the `-lboost_{libname}` flags that I can extend upon? Is it the `-I` flag?

EDIT: Now that the binary location specified by `--prefix` during build is done, I tried the same thing, even with `-L` and it didn't work. Refer to my answer below for the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, but it's not pretty:

I suspect it's because the other boost library binary is specified in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I could not load my own library in precedence using `-L /custom/path/...`.

Thus, I did:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/custom/path/...:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And it works.

**This is by no means a good answer because it doesn't really make this build process portable to users without the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` flag. Better answers will be approved instead of this.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you still need to provide the -L GCC option. 
Use -L to tell the compiler where to look for the boost libraries.

Also, make sure you used bjam/b2 to install boost in a proper place. That bin.v2 directory is used to build boost libraries and not install.